# Активити c MapKit вылетает (Java Android)

Tags: java, android, xml, yandexmapkit

Хочу подключить Яндекс.Карты (MapKit) в приложении. При запуске активити с картой приложение вылетает. **Код активити:**

```
package com.example.mobnetworkapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.yandex.mapkit.Animation;
import com.yandex.mapkit.MapKitFactory;
import com.yandex.mapkit.geometry.Point;
import com.yandex.mapkit.map.CameraPosition;
import com.yandex.mapkit.mapview.MapView;

public class MapEvents extends AppCompatActivity {
private final Point TARGET_LOCATION = new Point(59.945933, 30.320045);
private MapView mapView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map_events);
    String MAPKIT_API_KEY = "мой ключ";
    MapKitFactory.setApiKey(MAPKIT_API_KEY);
    MapKitFactory.initialize(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.map_events);
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.getMap().move(
            new CameraPosition(TARGET_LOCATION, 11.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),
            new Animation(Animation.Type.SMOOTH, 0),
            null);

}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mapView.onStop();
    MapKitFactory.getInstance().onStop();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mapView.onStart();
    MapKitFactory.getInstance().onStart();
}
}
```

**Код макета:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <com.yandex.mapkit.mapview.MapView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </com.yandex.mapkit.mapview.MapView>
```

**Содержание ошибки:**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ovapp/com.example.mobnetworkapp.MapEvents}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2 in com.example.ovapp:layout/map_events: Binary XML file line #2 in com.example.ovapp:layout/map_events: Error inflating class com.yandex.mapkit.mapview.MapView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3895)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4074)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:91)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:149)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:103)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2473)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:219)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8347)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1055)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2 in com.example.ovapp:layout/map_events: Binary XML file line #2 in com.example.ovapp:layout/map_events: Error inflating class com.yandex.mapkit.mapview.MapView
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2 in com.example.ovapp:layout/map_events: Error inflating class com.yandex.mapkit.mapview.MapView
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:864)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1016)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:971)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:669)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:536)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:483)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170)
        at com.example.mobnetworkapp.MapEvents.onCreate(MapEvents.java:19)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8085)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8073)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1320)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3868)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4074)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:91)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:149)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:103)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2473)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:219)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8347)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1055)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Required method parameter "key" cannot be null
    Exception stack trace (top 20 entries):
      # 0: 2282988  /data/app/com.example.ovapp-il0DVZcB2pTjOXTO7cN6Fg==/lib/arm64/libcom.yandex.runtime.so _ZN6yandex4maps7runtime9backtrace9BacktraceC2Ev
      # 1: 2307164  /data/app/com.example.ovapp-il0DVZcB2pTjOXTO7cN6Fg==/lib/arm64/libcom.yandex.runtime.so 
E/AndroidRuntime:   # 2: 2306600  /data/app/com.example.ovapp-il0DVZcB2pTjOXTO7cN6Fg==/lib/arm64/libcom.yandex.runtime.so _ZN6yandex4maps7runtime9ExceptionC2ERKNSt6__ndk112basic_stringIcNS3_11char_traitsIcEENS3_9allocatorIcEEEENS2_8SeverityE
      # 3: 3004084  /data/app/com.example.ovapp-il0DVZcB2pTjOXTO7cN6Fg==/lib/arm64/libcom.yandex.mapkit.so 
      # 4: 7831536  /data/app/com.example.ovapp-il0DVZcB2pTjOXTO7cN6Fg==/lib/arm64/libcom.yandex.mapkit.so Java_com_yandex_mapkit_internal_MapKitBinding_setApiKey__Ljava_lang_String_2
      # 5: 1360724  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so 
      # 6: 1323832  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so 
      # 7: 1384872  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so _ZN3art9ArtMethod6InvokeEPNS_6ThreadEPjjPNS_6JValueEPKc
      # 8: 3072868  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so _ZN3art11interpreter34ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_11ShadowFrameEtPNS_6JValueE
      # 9: 3053108  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so _ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE
      #10: 3112912  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so _ZN3art11interpreter20ExecuteSwitchImplCppILb0ELb0EEEvPNS0_17SwitchImplContextE
      #11: 1371100  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so 
      #12: 2879644  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so 
      #13: 2903436  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so _ZN3art11interpreter33ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridgeEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE
      #14: 3053080  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so _ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE
      #15: 3107752  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so _ZN3art11interpreter20ExecuteSwitchImplCppILb0ELb0EEEvPNS0_17SwitchImplContextE
      #16: 1371100  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so 
      #17: 2879644  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so 
      #18: 2903436  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so _ZN3art11interpreter33ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridgeEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE
      #19: 3053080  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so _ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE
    
        at com.yandex.mapkit.internal.MapKitBinding.setApiKey(Native Method)
        at com.yandex.mapkit.MapKitFactory.initialize(MapKitFactory.java:27)
        at com.yandex.mapkit.mapview.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:51)
        at com.yandex.mapkit.mapview.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:44)
            ... 26 more
```

Ключ получен в кабинете разработчика и активен. Библиотеки, зависимости и прочее подключено в соответствии с [инструкцией](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/mapkit/doc/3.x/concepts/android/quickstart-docpage/). Поиск по ошибке не дал результатов, всё не то. Подскажите, в чём может быть проблема в моём случае.

Comment: Ну судя по ошибке, ваша проблема в XML разметке. Ну и с ключом могут быть проблемы. Это весь когд разметки? ИЛи там есть еще что-то?

Comment: Это всё, больше ничего нет. Были мысли, что проблема в библиотеке, но ведь если бы она не подключилась, то среда ещё до компиляции подсветила бы многое красным. Вот и не знаю что за проблема, вроде всё сделано по инструкции

Comment: Единственное отличие от документации, то что вы вызываете `setContentView(R.layout.map_events);` дважды. Попробуйте убрать самый первый вызов, оставив лишь тот, который идёт сразу после `MapKitFactory.initialize(this);`

Comment: Более глупой ошибки у меня ещё не случалось :) Спасибо большое, всё заработало, буду внимательнее!